Mecha movie with robots synced to their pilots' movements
It's a movie that I watched with my dad when I was really young. I know it does not really help but I can't remember the year I watched it in. I'm 17 so I guess I watched it around 2001.
In my memory there are flashing scenes of the movie: it was a mecha movie. It had really cool animation graphics so I guess it was a japanese mecha; the robots were synced to their pilot's movements; and I can only remember the scene in which a robot was running in a desert and had to fight with another one that was seemingly pursuing him. I can only remember that scene because I thought it was really really cool how the pursued one flipped his sword backwards and stabbed the pursuer that was in his back as the finishing attack.
What movie could it be? I got lost through many Imdb titles and Youtube videos but I had no luck. Every mecha movie I stumbled upon were of robots controlled with their pilot seated. I suddenly remembered this movie after watching the trailer of Pacific Rim (2013) so I went through interviews of the director of that movie, but I had no luck.

Can you explain the part about the pilots? Was it a cartoon? These are the first questions I've got so far.

The pilots were not seated in front of many bottons and levers as in many robot movies. Instead, they controlled their robots similarly to how players played xBox in the movie The Island (2005). It was definitely an animation movie, the quality was similar to the animation quality of Final Fantasy VII: Advent of Children (2005)

I'm not sure if there's ever a desert scene, but you might be thinking of Pilot Candidate.  
From Wikipedia:

The Candidate for Goddess takes place a millennium after Star Year
  4084, when a cataclysmic event called "Crisis of Systems" resulted in
  the annihilation of four planetary systems. With Zion being the one
  planet left with the ability to sustain human life, mankind must cling
  to life in space colonies.1[2] Now in Star Year 5030, Zion is under
  constant threat of invasion by extraterrestrial life forms dubbed
  "Victim" (犠牲者 Giseisha?). In order to combat their alien foes, humans
  have developed a quintet of giant, mechanized weapons called
  "Ingrids", or "Goddesses" due to their female, humanoid
  resemblance.[2] A school called the "Goddess Operation Academy
  (G.O.A.)" is established to train the specific few which have the
  capability of piloting the Ingrids.1 They are typically young men
  and must meet several requirements: They must be in good health, must
  be 14 to 16 years of age, must have an EO blood type, and must possess
  the potential for "EX", superhuman abilities which secondarily link
  the pilot's nerves to the Ingrid's interface.1[2] As EX puts such a
  physical and mental strain on the pilot, replacements must be turned
  out by the G.O.A. within a reasonable amount of time.[3] Each pilot is
  also partnered with a female repairer, who maintains the Ingrid and
  manually blocks painful feedback from the Ingrid to the pilot during
  missions.1[2]
The plot of The Candidate for Goddess primarily focuses on Zero Enna,
  a brash trainee who has recently left colony homelife with his mother
  in order to pursue his dream of becoming an Ingrid pilot.[2] Shortly
  after arriving at the G.O.A., Zero becomes lost and is subconsciously
  called to a hangar by a mysterious voice, suddenly finding himself
  within the cockpit of one of the Ingrids.[3] As each Ingrid is
  specifically calibrated for their pilot, this would normally mean
  death. However, the Goddess instead links with Zero's nervous system
  and physically shows itself to him in a vision.[3] After a few
  moments, Zero is pulled free by the Ingrid's pilot, who then takes it
  into battle with the Victim. Zero is rushed to the academy's sick bay.


Try Daimos and see if that was it. It is pretty old. Older than you mentioned. I think it was called starbirds in English.
It is an anime from the 80s. Earth is fighting aliens that look like angels (wings and all). The aliens live in a crystal pyramid thing by Jupiter. The robots are controlled by movement and not levers as such. It isn't a 3d or computer animated video though. Purely hand drawn cartoon.
